# How does typekit.com work ? @font-face

Tags: php, css, ruby, fonts

How does [typekit.com](http://typekit.com) work ?

There are many site like typekit allow css designers to use custom fonts ? but how ? How can I make a site like typekit ? What technology is used ? Are there any open source ?

Answer (score 1):

Their loader is open source if that's any help: http://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Comment: What do you mean by "index file"? Typekit is basically a Javascript based system which uses various obfuscation methods to protect the copyright of the fonts involved.

Comment: Do mean I can use my own font by javascript code in my site without typekit.com ? ( it doesn't need a php code ! ).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to embed custom fonts in a webpage. Take a look at http://jonraasch.com/blog/embedding-custom-fonts for example.

Although, your question is not clear - are you just trying to embed fonts, or to obfuscate them as well.

Comment: Why do designers use sIFR if they can use @font-face ? what is wrong with @font-face ?

Comment: The article linked above states that it's not supported in recent versions of FF and Opera.